# Slim framework route param settings

Tags: backbone.js, routes, slim

**I am trying to build a live chat for a webshop, using Slim Framework for routing.**

My messages database table has a column named

```
     message_key
```

This contains a generated md5.

Everytime when an user decides to chat, he/she will post a message to this table with a generated md5 string. This way I can return all messages which have the same value in

```
    message_key
```

**When I call my route:**

```
/api/msgs/60f0c8ce4733094b68af71c471cf1139
```

it throws me an error:

```
{"error":{"text":SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
 '60f0c8ce4733094b68af71c471cf1139' in 'where clause'}}
```

But when I change the value of the `message_key` column to a number I do not get an error:

```
    /api/msgs/7272
```

Then I get pretty JSON in return.

How does this happen?

**Is there a way I can use various characters as a route param?**

Comment: It's not clear what this has to do with Backbone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you get a problem like this, it means that you are trying to match with a column instead of a value.  In this case it is needed to wrap the VALUE in the WHERE clause:

```
 WHERE message_key = '$key';
```

Before I tried to do it like this:

```
 WHERE message_key = $key;
```

...this results in a query that tries to match a column named 60f0c8ce4733094b68af71c471cf1139

_**So always check if you are matching VALUES or COLUMNS _**

Answer (score 0):

To answer this, we need more information. It's clear from the error that at least some of the time the message key is set as the column name in your SQL.

Have you defined a route with a segment for the message_key...
'/api/msgs(/:message_key)'
or just
'/api/msgs' ?